# Странное поведение деструктора класса в C++

Tags: c++, классы, конструктор

Пишу класс для матриц(задание в универе). Перегрузил оператор, все работает, но почему-то tmp2 удаляется во время выполнение операции сложения

Поля класса матрицы(3 штуки)

```
unsigned int m, n;//строка, столбец
float** matrix;
```

Перегрузка оператора:

```
FloatMatrix operator + (FloatMatrix m2)
{
    unsigned int maxM, maxN, minM,minN;
    if (this->m > m2.m) {
        maxM = this->m;
        minM = m2.m;
    }
    else
    {
        maxM = m2.m;
        minM = this->m;
    }

    if (this->n > m2.n) {
        maxN = this->n;
        minN = m2.n;
    }
    else
    {
        maxN = m2.n;
        minN = this->n;
    }
    // Создать новую матрицу максимальной размерности и в нее класть результат
    
    FloatMatrix res = FloatMatrix(maxM, maxN);

    for (unsigned int i = 0; i < this->m; i++)
    {
        for (unsigned int j = 0; j < this->n; j++)
            res.matrix[i][j] = this->matrix[i][j];
    }

    for (unsigned int i = 0; i < m2.m; i++)
    {
        for (unsigned int j = 0; j < m2.n; j++)
            res.matrix[i][j] += m2.matrix[i][j];
    }

    return FloatMatrix(res.m,res.n, res.matrix);

}
```

Код самой программы:

```
FloatMatrix tmp = FloatMatrix(2, 5);//матрица 2*5
FloatMatrix tmp2 = FloatMatrix(2);//Матрица 2*2
tmp.FillFloat(2.0);
tmp2.FillFloat(3.0);

tmp1.Print();//Без проблем
tmp2.Print();//без проблем

FloatMatrix tmp3 = tmp + tmp2;

tmp1.Print();//без проблем
tmp3.Print();//без проблем
tmp2.Print();//Исключение
```

Пояснения: если пытаться вывести tmp и tmp3, то никаких проблем нет. При попытке вывести tmp2, поля m,n равны 2(как и должно быть)? но вот обратиться к tmp2.matrix[0][0] нельзя(я сейчас написал полный путь, как он пытается обратиться, я знаю, что он недоступен извне, обращаюсь через внутренний метод Print()). Получается, что указатель tmp2.matrix[i] был очищен. Код ошибки:`Необработанное исключение по адресу 0x002538A8 в Matrix.exe: 0xC0000005: нарушение прав доступа при чтении по адресу 0xDDDDDDDD.`

Comment: FloatMatrix tmp2 = FloatMatrix(2);
Вот тут ты создал двумерный массив или одинарный?

Comment: Двумерный массив размерности 2*2, ниже уже написали что не так

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Предполагаю, что конструктора копирования с **глубоким** копированием нет. В результате, из-за того, что тут

```
FloatMatrix operator + (FloatMatrix m2)
```

передача по значению, выполняется копирование `tmp2`, и теперь на одну и ту же память указывают 2 указателя. После завершения суммирования копия удаляется, и указатели в `tmp2` указывают на уже освобожденную память.

Ну, а в деструкторе выполняется освобождение уже освобожденного...

Ну так что, я прав насчет копирующего конструктора?...

Comment: Правы... Даже не знал о таком

Comment: FloatMatrix (const FloatMatrix &obj)
    {      
        m = obj.m;
        n= obj.n;
        matrix = new float* [m];
 for (unsigned int i = 0; i < m; i++)
 {
  matrix[i] = new float[n];
  for (unsigned int j = 0; j < n; j++)
   matrix[i][j] = obj[m][n];
 }


    }

Так получается?

Comment: Спасибо, заработало Плюс в самом перегрузе написать не m2, а &m2